# Fetch documents that don't contain UID in array

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a tinder like system where you can match with people/skip them.

When a profile gets skipped, it should add a uid to their bookmarks field.

It does this all successfully, but now I only want to fetch the documents that don't contain the uid.

My code is below:

```
    func fetchInitialCards(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot?, completion: @escaping PaginatedCompletionHandler) {
    guard let lastDoc = document else {
        db.collection(FIRCollections.DiscoveryProfiles.rawValue)
            .whereField("bookmarks", isNotEqualTo: "WoLU87LALUZOcMTu0wszo8jeBQF3")
            .limit(to: 1)
            .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
                let documents = snapshot.documents
                completion(documents, error)
            }
        return
    }
    
    db.collection(FIRCollections.DiscoveryProfiles.rawValue)
        .whereField("bookmarks", isNotEqualTo: "WoLU87LALUZOcMTu0wszo8jeBQF3")
        .limit(to: 1)
        .start(afterDocument: lastDoc)
        .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
            let documents = snapshot.documents
            completion(documents, error)
        }
}
```

The bookmarks field is a string array and contains multiple different uid values, so 'isnotequalto' doesnt work.

I can't make a check after the documents have been fetched as I limit the documents to 1, so it would be marked as nil otherwise.

The result I'm looking for is like an 'ArrayContains', but the opposite of that, like 'arraydoesntcontain'.

Comment: Firestore can only index and query for data that exists. It won't scan all documents in a collection to find out what doesn't exist - that would be massively inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of in Firestore to "find docs with an array that does NOT have value xyz".

Firestore indexes fields and does its searches against those indexes. Searching for "absence of a value in an array" is likely not supported in the Firestore query semantics.

If there were such support, I'd expect to see it described [in this section of the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators) and/or mentioned [in the limitations section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations).